# How to display map in React native expo web using mapbox-gl

Tags: react-native, expo, mapbox-gl, react-native-web

I am building an app and web app in react native expo. for a map, I am using `@rnmapbox/maps` package for Android and Ios but using this package map not working on the web. so, I have installed `mapbox-gl` package for the web, but it only shows earth-view on the web instead of the map.

I am sharing the code that I have written for the web.

```
import mapboxgl from 'mapbox-gl';

class WebPackconatiner extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {
            lng: -70.9,
            lat: 42.35,
            zoom: 9
        };
        this.mapContainer = React.createRef();
    }

    componentDidMount() {
        const { lng, lat, zoom } = this.state;
        const map = new mapboxgl.Map({
            container: this.mapContainer.current,
            style: 'mapbox://styles/mapbox/streets-v12',
            center: [lng, lat],
            zoom: zoom
        });
    }

    render() {
        console.log("ref", this.mapContainer);
        return (
            <View>
                <View ref={this.mapContainer} style={{ height: '400px' }} />
            </View>
        );
    }
}

export default WebPackconatiner;
```

I am attaching the preview that I am getting on the web.

[image]

How can I get an actual map on the web in React native expo?

Thank you in advance!!!